# Scroll Restoration on location.pathname change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

Page should scroll to top only when location.pathname is changed, React.memo should return true only if pathname is changed not the queryparams. But the page is scrolled to the top even when should update returns false.

```
const shouldUpdate = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return prevProps.location.pathname !== nextProps.location.pathname;
};

const ScrollToTop = ({ history }) => {
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    const unlisten = history.listen(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
    return () => {
      unlisten();
    };
  }, []);
  return (null);
};

export default withRouter(React.memo(ScrollToTop, shouldUpdate));

<React.Fragment>
    <Router>
      <ScrollToTop />
      <Switch>
        .
        .
        .
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </React.Fragment>
```

Comment: Will this help? https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/scroll-restoration

Comment: This is the very first solution that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

You should call `scrollTo` method using `useEffect` hook

```
  useEffect(() => {
    document.querySelector("#root").scrollTo(0, 0);
  }, []);
```